# Text format chooser in Tkinter possible?

Tags: python-3.x, text, tkinter, filechooser

Is is possible to use a "Text chooser" in Tkinter?

I mean a dialog box like "File chooser" or "Color chooser"!

[image]

Comment: You mean a dialog for choosing a font?

Comment: Exactely, but it seems that there is FontChooser integrated in Tkinter!